# c++ extracting command line arguments

Tags: string, visual-c++, command-line-arguments

Visual Studio 2013 C++. what  I am trying to do is, I will ask for a string and extract each letter from that string. (I know it is already char) but I dont know how to extract each letter, and find out number of chars entered. I do not know how to stop the command line window. getchar() only gets one char but the user may enter several chars continuously, like a string. Any idea? Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string firstarg;
        if (argc < 1) 
        {
            //Check see if str passed
            cout << "No string entered....";

        }
        else
        {
            firstarg = argv[1];
            cout << firstarg;
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you re-state the question? It is very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: In the above code there is no need to "stop the command line window". Make use of the first argument argc i.e. the Argument Count to determine  number of strings passed to the program.